# R from C -- Simplest Possible Helloworld

Tags: c, windows, r

What is the simplest possible C function for starting the R interpreter, passing in a small expression (eg, 2+2), and getting out the result?  I'm trying to compile with MingW on Windows.

Comment: good point... clarified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to call R from C?

Look at [section 8.1 in the Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Embedding-R-under-Unix_002dalikes) manual. You should also look into the "tests" directory (download the source package extract it and you'll have the tests directory).  A similar question was previously asked on R-Help and [here was the example](http://n4.nabble.com/Qs-on-calling-R-from-C-td923995.html):

```
#include <Rinternals.h> 
#include <Rembedded.h> 

SEXP hello() { 
  return mkString("Hello, world!\n"); 
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  SEXP x; 
  Rf_initEmbeddedR(argc, argv); 
  x = hello(); 
  return x == NULL;             /* i.e. 0 on success */ 
}
```

The simple example from the R manual is like so:

```
 #include <Rembedded.h>

 int main(int ac, char **av)
 {
     /* do some setup */
     Rf_initEmbeddedR(argc, argv);
     /* do some more setup */

     /* submit some code to R, which is done interactively via
         run_Rmainloop();

         A possible substitute for a pseudo-console is

         R_ReplDLLinit();
         while(R_ReplDLLdo1() > 0) {
           add user actions here if desired
         }
      */
     Rf_endEmbeddedR(0);
     /* final tidying up after R is shutdown */
     return 0;
 }
```

Incidentally, you might want to consider using **Rinside** instead: Dirk provides [a nice "hello world" example](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) on the project homepage.

In you're interested in calling C from R, here's my original answer:

This isn't exactly "hello world", but here are some good resources:

- Jay Emerson recently gave a talk on R package development at the New York useR group, and he provided some very nice examples of using C from within R.  Have a look at [the paper from this discussion on his website](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jay/Rmeetup/Rmeetup.pdf), starting on page 9.  All the related source code is here: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jay/Rmeetup/MyToolkitWithC/.
- The course taught at Harvard by Gopi Goswami in 2005: [C-C++-R (in Statistics)](http://www.stat.harvard.edu/ccr2005/).  This includes extensive examples and source code.

Comment: Many thanks... I was missing the R init function calls... oops.  The examples from you (and others) have been extremely help (too bad I can't give accepted answers to a few others too... :) ).

Answer (score 10):

Here you go. It's the main function, but you should be able to adapt it to a more general purpose function. This example builds an R expression from C calls and also from a C string. You're on your own for the compiling on windows, but I've provided compile steps on linux:

```
 /* simple.c */
 #include <Rinternals.h>
 #include <Rembedded.h>
 #include <R_ext/Parse.h>
 int
 main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    char *localArgs[] = {"R", "--no-save","--silent"};
    SEXP e, tmp, ret;
    ParseStatus status;
    int i;

    Rf_initEmbeddedR(3, localArgs);

    /* EXAMPLE #1 */

    /* Create the R expressions "rnorm(10)" with the R API.*/
    PROTECT(e = allocVector(LANGSXP, 2));
    tmp = findFun(install("rnorm"), R_GlobalEnv);
    SETCAR(e, tmp);
    SETCADR(e, ScalarInteger(10));

    /* Call it, and store the result in ret */
    PROTECT(ret = R_tryEval(e, R_GlobalEnv, NULL));

    /* Print out ret */
    printf("EXAMPLE #1 Output: ");
    for (i=0; i<length(ret); i++){
        printf("%f ",REAL(ret)[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    UNPROTECT(2);


    /* EXAMPLE 2*/

    /* Parse and eval the R expression "rnorm(10)" from a string */
    PROTECT(tmp = mkString("rnorm(10)"));
    PROTECT(e = R_ParseVector(tmp, -1, &status, R_NilValue));
    PROTECT(ret = R_tryEval(VECTOR_ELT(e,0), R_GlobalEnv, NULL));

    /* And print. */
    printf("EXAMPLE #2 Output: ");
    for (i=0; i<length(ret); i++){
        printf("%f ",REAL(ret)[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    UNPROTECT(3);
    Rf_endEmbeddedR(0);
    return(0);
 }
```

Compile steps:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/share/R/include/ -c -ggdb simple.c
$ gcc -o simple simple.o  -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/R/lib R_HOME=/usr/lib/R ./simple
EXAMPLE #1 Output: 0.164351 -0.052308 -1.102335 -0.924609 -0.649887 0.605908 0.130604 0.243198 -2.489826 1.353731
EXAMPLE #2 Output: -1.532387 -1.126142 -0.330926 0.672688 -1.150783 -0.848974 1.617413 -0.086969 -1.334659 -0.313699
```

Comment: Can it be compiled under VS2008 (MS Compiler)? What are the arguments?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think any of the above has answered the question - which was to evaluate 2 + 2 ;). To use a string expression would be something like:

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <R_ext/Parse.h>
#include <Rembedded.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SEXP x;
    ParseStatus status;
    const char* expr = "2 + 2";

    Rf_initEmbeddedR(argc, argv);

    x = R_ParseVector(mkString(expr), 1, &status, R_NilValue);
    if (TYPEOF(x) == EXPRSXP) { /* parse returns an expr vector, you want the first */
        x = eval(VECTOR_ELT(x, 0), R_GlobalEnv);
        PrintValue(x);
    }

    Rf_endEmbeddedR(0);

    return 0;
}
```

This lacks error checking, obviously, but works:

```
Z:\>gcc -o e.exe e.c -IC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-213~1.0/include -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-213~1.0/bin/i386 -lR
Z:\>R CMD e.exe
[1] 4
```

(To get the proper commands for your R use `R CMD SHLIB e.c` which gives you the relevant compiler flags)

You can also construct the expression by hand if it's simple enough - e.g., for `rnorm(10)` you would use

```
SEXP rnorm = install("rnorm");
SEXP x = eval(lang2(rnorm, ScalarInteger(10)), R_GlobalEnv);
```

Comment: Can it be compiler under Visual Studio (MS compiler)? What are the parameters?

Comment: No, VC is not officially supported, the native compiler is MinGW. There are may be ways to combine VC code with R (e.g. through DLLs), but it is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: I've compiled the code under Visual Studio (MS Compiler) :). To do so, the R.lib library should be created manually.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't do much better than the [**inline**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) package (which supports C, C++ and Fortran):

```
library(inline)
fun <- cfunction(signature(x="ANY"), 
                 body='printf("Hello, world\\n"); return R_NilValue;')
res <- fun(NULL)
```

which will print 'Hello, World' for you.  And you don't even know where / how / when the compiler and linker are invoked. [ The R_NilValue is R's NULL version of a SEXP and the `.Call()` signature used here requires that you return a SEXP -- see the 'Writing R Extensions' manual which you can't really avoid here. ]

You will then take such code and wrap it in a package.  We had great success with using 
[**inline**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) for the 
[**Rcpp**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) unit tests (over 200 and counting now) and some of the examples.

Oh, and this [**inline**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) example will work on any OS. Even Windoze provided you have the R package building tool chain installed, in the PATH etc pp.

***Edit:*** I misread the question.  What you want is essentially what the [**littler**](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) front-end does (using pure C) and what the [**RInside**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RInside) classes factored-out for C++.

Jeff and I never bothered with porting [**littler**](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) to Windoze, but [**RInside**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RInside) did work there in most-recent release. So you should be able to poke around the build recipes and create a C-only variant of [**RInside**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RInside) so that you can feed expression to an embedded R process.  I suspect that you still want something like [**Rcpp**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) for the clue as it gets tedious otherwise.

***Edit 2:*** And as Shane mentions, there are indeed a few examples in the R sources in tests/Embedding/ along with a Makefile.win.  Maybe that is the simplest start if you're willing to learn about R internals.

Comment: True, but that is C++... I'd rather a C example for the moment. Rcpp looks very simple to use, though.

Comment: Yes, I edited accordingly.  Inline works fine without Rcpp though.  But once you actually want to exchange data, I'd go Rcpp even though you may feel that C++ is more complex than C. It doesn't have to be.

Comment: That's interesting, but the opposite of what I am looking for.  I am interested in calling R from (possibly legacy) C code, not the other way around... I'm sorry if the original question wasn't clear.  This info is helpful too, though. :)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. In that case, try 'littler' and 'RInside' and I will amend my answer.