# Calling R Script from within C-Code

Tags: c++, c, r, interface

Is there a way to call an R-Script within C-Code?

I did find the R Api for C (chaper 6. of the 'Writing R Extensions' manual), but as far as I understood this does "only" allow to call the C-Implementation of R. Of cause I could call the R-Script via shell, but that's no solution for me, since this does not allow proper passing of data (at least no if I don't what to write the data into a Csv-File or something like this).

Is there a easy way of using the R to C parser beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

is there some reason that you don't want to embed it?  This is covered in this question: [R from C — Simplest Possible Helloworld…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463437/r-from-c-simplest-possible-helloworld)

Answer (score 0):

I found this works to run Rscript in C++ for Mac systems:

```
string r_command = "/usr/local/bin/RScript --vanilla /Users/<enter file path here>/your_script.R \"" + argument_1 + "\" " + "\"" + argument_2 + "\"";

system(r_command.c_str());
```

You can also pass variables into the arguments. Watch out on the escapes. Things can get tricky.