# Problem running C code that has R in it

Tags: r

I am using following thread as basis for writing C code with R in it
[R from C -- Simplest Possible Helloworld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463437/r-from-c-simplest-possible-helloworld/6478705#)

i could compile and link c code  with following cmds

```
$ gcc -Wall -I/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/R/R-2.13.0/include -c -ggdb Rhello.c 

$ gcc -L/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/R/R-2.13.0/bin/i386 -o Rhello Rhello.o -lR
```

However I canNOT run the resulting executable with following command:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/R/R-2.13.0/bin R_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/R/R-2.13.0 ./Rhello
```

All I get is a popup window saying "..stopped working...". I am on widowsvista & cygwin. can someone tell me what is the wrong with the above cmd.

thanks 
kris

Comment: Can you confirm that you *can* compile and run a simple (non-R linking) C file that does the usual printf("hello world\n") test? Just so we know your basic compiler isn't broken before we start hunting problems on what's essentially Microsoft's worst OS ever (yet).

Comment: Also cygwin wtf? You need the MinGW toolchain as documented in the documentation. Unless you've managed to compile R with cygwin of course...

Comment: Cygwin is not broken and it works just fine for regular C and C++ programming.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at getting  [RTools](http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/) and reading [the basics](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) and perhaps [more documentation](http://www.math.univ-montp2.fr/~pudlo/R_files/call_R.pdf)