# Any libraries that provide betainv for C++

Tags: c++, math, g++, libraries, beta-distribution

Does anyone know of any libraries that provide the `betainv` function in c++?

The `betainv(x,a,b)` computes the `xth` quantile of a beta distribution with parameters `a,b`

Comment: Boost does: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/beta_dist.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Boost C++ Libraries](http://boost.org) have a [beta distribution](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/beta_dist.html), and all boost distributions include the inverse cumulative density function: [Quantile](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/nmp.html#math_toolkit.dist.dist_ref.nmp.h11).

e.g.

```
double probability=...;
beta_distribution<> mybeta(2, 5);
cout << quantile(mybeta, probability);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I believe that API of [*Wolfram Mathematica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CLanguageInterface.html), [*MatLab*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4202/Solving-Engineering-Problems-Using-MATLAB-C-API) or [*R*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463437/r-from-c-simplest-possible-helloworld) should provide such method.

Comment: Did not know Matlab had an API, this should do the trick! Will accept once timer lets me