# What are the steps necessary to pass R objects to a Rust program?

Tags: r, rust

Both R and Rust can interface with C code, so I think it is very possible. I am a bit unclear about how to proceed, however.

I have read these sections looking for answers:

1. [R-extensions System-and-foreign-language-interfaces](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#System-and-foreign-language-interfaces)
2. [The Rust foreign function interface guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/guide-ffi.html)

But while I am well-versed in `R` I am *not* a systems programmer and confused by what the build-chain looks like for such an endeavor.

Using `Rinternals.h` would be ideal, but I would settle for the simpler `.C` interface as well.

Comment: Potentially useful - [R from C — Simplest Possible Helloworld](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463437/r-from-c-simplest-possible-helloworld)

Comment: Do you want to call R from Rust, or Rust from R?  If you the latter, look at `.Call()` rather than `.C()` which nobody should use anymore.  Rcpp may help you with an intermediate layer.

Comment: I would like to call Rust code from within R and use Rust libraries on objects in my R session.

Comment: The you should be able to (easily) go from R to C++ via Rcpp. At that point the answer by @swizard becomes usable as is.   If you are interested, we could cook up a little demo up as an example in the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) -- as there is eg one of [embedding Python via Boost](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-python/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If R can interface with C code, so it is no problem at all to compile shared library from Rust code which exposes C-style functions.

Then you can easily use your library as it was written in C or C++. Of course, you will not able to use Rust object and libraries directly from R, you will have to make appropriate C interface for converting their functions.

Here is how can I do that for SBCL, and I suppose it would be very similar for R:

#### On Rust side

Some code:

`% cat experiment.rs`

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_int, c_char};
use std::{ffi, str};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_code_string_to_int(s: *const c_char, r: *mut c_int) -> c_int { 
    let string = String::from_utf8_lossy(unsafe { ffi::CStr::from_ptr(s).to_bytes() });
    match <isize as str::FromStr>::from_str(&*string) {
        Ok(value) => { unsafe { *r = value as c_int }; 0 },
        Err(_) => -1,
    }
}
```

Then I'm making shared lib:

```
% rustc --crate-type dylib experiment.rs
% nm -a libexperiment.dylib | grep rust_code_string_to_int
0000000000001630 t __ZN23rust_code_string_to_int10__rust_abiE
00000000000015e0 T _rust_code_string_to_int
```

#### Next, on SBCL side

Now I'm just loading my shared lib and then I have access to my `rust_code_string_to_int` function:

```
RUST> (sb-alien:load-shared-object "libexperiment.dylib")
#P"libexperiment.dylib"
RUST> (sb-alien:with-alien ((result sb-alien:int 0))  
          (values (sb-alien:alien-funcall (sb-alien:extern-alien "rust_code_string_to_int" 
                                                                 (sb-alien:function sb-alien:int 
                                                                                    (sb-alien:c-string :external-format :utf-8)
                                                                                    (sb-alien:* sb-alien:int)))
                                          (sb-alien:make-alien-string "42")
                                          (sb-alien:addr result))
                  result))
0
42
```

Answer (score 10):

I have been struggling on this for a while as well, but once you know how I'ts actually not that difficult.

First create a Rust library following these instructions: [rust-inside-other-languages](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/rust-inside-other-languages.html).
Here is an example Rust library:

```
//src/lib.rs

#[no_mangle]
pub fn kelvin_to_fahrenheit(n: f64) -> f64 {
    n * 9.0/5.0 - 459.67
}
```

If you follow the instructions in [rust-inside-other-languages](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/rust-inside-other-languages.html), then you should be able to generate a `*.so` (or `*.dll` or `.dylib`, depending on your system). Let's presume this compiled file is called `libtempr.so`.

Now create a C++ file which will pass the functions you need to R:

```
//embed.cpp

extern "C" {
    double kelvin_to_fahrenheit(double);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double cpp_kelvin_to_fahrenheit(double k) {
  double f = kelvin_to_fahrenheit(k);
  return(f);
}
```

Now before starting R, make sure the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains the directory where the shared object generated previously (`libtempr.so`) is stored. In the shell do:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/path/to/shared/object:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ rstudio # I highly recommend using Rstudio for your R coding
```

Finally in Rstudo, write this file:

```
library(Rcpp)

Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-L/home/sam/path/to/shared/object -ltempr")

sourceCpp("/home/sam/path/to/embed.cpp", verbose = T, rebuild = T)

cpp_kelvin_to_fahrenheit(300)
```

- Be careful that in `Sys.setenv` the `-L` option points to the directory containing your Rust shared object.
- Also be careful that `-l` option is the name of your shared object without the `lib` prefix and without the `.so` (or whatever it is on your system) postfix.
- Using `Sys.setenv` in R to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable **DOES NOT WORK**. Export the variable before starting R.
- The `verbose` option is there so that you can see what `Rcpp` does to compile your C++ file. Notice how the options in `PKG_LIBS` above are used for compiling your C++ file.
- The `rebuild` options is there to force a rebuild of the C++ file every time you run this line of R code.

If you did everything well, then run the R file above in the interactive console and it should output `80.33` when you reach the last line.

If anything is not clear, ask in the comments, and I'll try to improve my answer.

Hope it helped :)

---

Final note, the base functions `dyn.load` and `.C` can be used as an alternative approach. But this requires writing a lot more boilerplate wrapper code than this approach.