# C function to divide numeric vector into different ranges

Tags: c, vector

Is there is any function in c equivalent to cut function in R?
The cut function in r, divides the numeric vector into different ranges based on the 'breaks' and give labels to each range.

Comment: is this option to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463996/4635560 ?